# javascript giving an ID of a image another src

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a function: if I click on clickF (=image) then the image of clickF will swap places with showF (= also an image).

```
      function switchF() {

       if (document.getElementById("clickF").src = "images site/KT.png")
       {
           document.getElementById("clickF").src = "images site/GM.png";
           document.getElementById("showF").src = "images site/KT.png";
       }
          else {
           document.getElementById("clickF").src = "images site/KT.png";
           document.getElementById("showF").src = "images site/GM.png";
       }


   }
```

I think I've made a mistake in the if condition but after exactly 2 hours of research, I haven't found anything correct for my purpose. when this is running, my first click works but afterwards when normally the else needs to work it stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the if statement. You are using only one = which is an assignment. To compare two elements, you need to use === , see this:

```
if (document.getElementById("clickF").src === "images site/KT.png")
```

Comment: strange enough 3*= doesn't do anything but 1*= runs the THEN action.

Comment: Using one equal, the "outcome" of that is the string you just assigned, and for Javascript, everything except 0 and null are considered "true" values.

Comment: and === does nothing? that seems very strange because either way, it must be either FALSE or TRUE - what does your console say, is there an error or something?

Comment: "cannot find context with specified id"

Comment: @SpeedyJoeri that has nothing to do with the = or === but rather with the IDs you are looking for (clickF/showF)